# htaccess rewrite url remove subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite

`http://www.example.com/directory/folder/*`

to

`http://www.example.com/directory/*`

the htaccess file is in `directory`

this is my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /directory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: If you have files in directory folder, How to access it? Please give me solution. I tried above code but it allways redirect to the subfolder's index.php page and I'm using Codeigniter inside of the subfolder

Comment: @Sparkup - For core php, it is working absolutely fine for me. Thanks a lot for sharing this solution.

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) /directory/$1 [L]
```

Or you can go without [L] or use [R] instead.