# how to Remove Sub directory name from URL with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

My URL was

> http://demo.example.com/parentFolder/

but i have to redirect it to child folder, URL as

> http://demo.example.com/parentFolder/ChildFolder/

i have redirect it in htaccess as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?demo.example.com/parentFolder$
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ChildFolder/


       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ChildFolder/$1

       #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?demo.example.com/parentFolder$
       RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ChildFolder/ [L]

</IfModule>
```

but didn't remove sub folder(ChildFolder) from URL.
i want to access childFolder after redirect but want to hide childFolder from URL.

Comment: What url are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @starkeen i want to acess childFolder and also want to hide childFolder from url

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?demo.example.com/parentFolder$` will never match as `HTTP_HOST` means `your domain name` not the path.

Comment: but it is redirecting

Comment: @starkeen do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Someone already gives the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795134/htaccess-rewrite-url-remove-subdirectory

Comment: @SMNTB after redirecting to child folder it doesn't remove child folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rule in **parentFolder/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove ChildFolder from URL show in browser
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(parentFolder)/ChildFolder/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [R=301,NE,L]

# add ChildFolder internally

RewriteRule ^$ ChildFolder/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!ChildFolder/).*$ ChildFolder/$0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I have applied it working perfectly but i face one more issue as i applied it for angular project, i have to change its base path also for index.html, when i change base path it doesn't get JS files etc what should i do for it except to write path statically.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about AngularJS. May be, you need to add `<base href="/base-path/" />`  just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML to resolve `js/css/images` path.

Comment: if i add path then it shows children folder path in URL

Comment: i cannot share real URL here it's confidential. Although URL is like  demo.example.com/ParentFolder/ChildrenFolder/  .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165017/discussion-between-hu7sy-and-anubhava).

Comment: Thanks buddy now its working fine i just remove children folder name from base path.