# htaccess mod_rewrite to transform url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php project using a directory structure and I want to create pretty urls.
Basically I want to remove ".php" extension of each file and delete path stuff between localhost and the filename.

Example:

transform this => `localhost/myproject/views/pages/login/login.php`

into this => `localhost/myproject/login`

I know I have to configure .htaccess mod_rewrite but I don't know how exactly to be honest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite url remove subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795134/htaccess-rewrite-url-remove-subdirectory)

Comment: Have you seen this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained?

Comment: I'll have a look...

Answer (score 0):

Try and add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It should basically remove all the .php extensions from being showed.

Comment: That wasn't really the question though. (Also you shouldn't copy and paste such snippets around without documenting a source/origin link. A little late now for this one, of course.)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work at all. It remove .php extensions but it doesn't delete de middle path. Furthermore the application does not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I've solved it. I have a index.php file in the root folder so any url will redirect to that file adding `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` in .htaccess using a query string with the view name I want to show. Then I had to rewrite all links to look like "/myproject/name_of_the_view" inside of the project