# check if Url contains special character like #

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have site setup in `wordpress` as root folder like `/wordpress` and one `angular` site setup in sub folder `/wordpress/angular`.

Currently if user visits `url` like `mydomain.com/wordpress/sample-page`, it displays `wp` page and if visits like  `mydomain.com/wordpress/angular/#/sample-page` or `mydomain.com/wordpress/angular/#/parent-page/child-page`, it displays `angular` page.

After #/, whatever it is, it should stay on angular page. Currently it is staying, but `angular` in url should not be shown

**I want to remove `angular` from `url` if user visits `angular` page.**

So, I put `.htaccess` file in `wordpress` folder like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)angular
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ angular/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now if I visit `url` like `mydomain.com/wordpress/#/any-url`, it should stay on `angular`' page but not working.

I guess I need to check if url contains `#`, then make it redirect to `angular` folder. As it is a `special character`, how to make some condition on above code.

I am taking ref from

[htaccess rewrite url remove subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795134/htaccess-rewrite-url-remove-subdirectory)

[htaccess redirect if URL contains a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220377/htaccess-redirect-if-url-contains-a-certain-string)

I am not much expert on `htaccess` config. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So... to be clear, if someone visits `mydomain.com/wordpress/angular/#/sample-page` you want them to be redirected to `mydomain.com/wordpress/sample-page`?

Comment: @Shoelaced, No it should stay on angular page.After `#/` whatever it is, it should stay on angular page. Currently it is staying, but `angular` in url should not be shown

Comment: The fragment portion of a URL does not even get send to the server - so you can not use it to base any decisions inside .htaccess on it.

Comment: which portion you referring?

Comment: The `#/sample-page` part.